# Does JADclipse working in MacOS?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jadclipse

**Mac version**: OSX Maverick
**Eclipse Version**: Tried both Mars and the previous Luna release.

---

Just gotten Eclipse a few days ago and i run across JADclipse, been wanting to look through class files so I went to download it

Spent the past 2 days trying to get it to work, I have done all the steps required:

- File Association for jad
- Made JADclipse Viewer as Default
- Eclipse -clean

Despite that it still gives me the error that

```
The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput').
```

Can anyone help out?

[Full error details](http://pastebin.com/g50MnSvt)

Comment: How are you trying to actually open the file?

Comment: tried both dragging the file into eclipse and doing File > Open file

Answer (score 0):

The message is saying that the viewer cannot deal with `FileStoreEditorInput`. This input is used when you try to open a file which is not in the Eclipse Workspace. So presumably the viewer can only open files which are in the current workspace.

Comment: Tried both Luna and Mars, i placed the class file into the workspace but is still not working ,same error occurred again.